# How to set defaultsort in display table dynamically

Tags: jquery, displaytag

How to set the `defaultsort` attribute in display table through any variable of jsp or JQuery ?

Adding details,

I am using display table as below:

```
<display:table name="testList" sort="external" defaultsort="1" id="element">
  <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true" sortName="id" />
  <display:column property="firstName" sortable="true" sortName="firstName" title="First Name" />
  <display:column property="lastName" sortable="true" sortName="lastName" title="Last Name" />
  <display:column property="address" sortable="true" sortName="address" title="Email Address"/>
</display:table>
```

How to change the value of `defaultsort` based on some condition in Java script.